# Combining the rows of data from sheets with serial numbers in colA using Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

How do I generate the serial numbers in Colum A of the data that is combined from 2 different spreadsheets?

I have tried with

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A2:G;Sheet2!A2:G}, "select * where Col5 is not null")
```

[Here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15E6-D7Bi6f_JLq4ySve16dxrLhQya_wcNzZkqbT5kqM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{"serial number"; ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 QUERY({Sheet1!E2:E; Sheet2!E2:E}, "where Col1 is not null", 0))))}, 
 QUERY({Sheet1!B1:G; Sheet2!B2:G}, "where Col4 is not null", 1)})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**How to create a list of sequential serial numbers based on another column.**

If you want to use your existing formula (with a minor adjustment), in cell `A2` you can use

```
=SEQUENCE(COUNT(B2:B))
```

[image: create a list of sequential serial numbers]

The minor adjustment in your `B2` existing formula would be

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!B2:G;Sheet2!B2:G}, "select * where Col4 is not null")
```

Functions used:

- [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)
- [`COUNT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093620)